# How to make Visual C# Form Applications resize all control automatically with form resize in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#

I have been developing windows form apps for school for a while but I couldn't find how to make all controls resize with the form like normal native windows apps. I am using C# in this case. I hope this was a good enough question to ask, please comment for question pointers, I have gotten a few worse reviews some deserved and some I don't know exactly why. I'm a student programmer as well so most help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've written a lot of native Windows apps (mostly using MFC in the 90s). I don't remember controls resizing magically. Can you provide a [mcve] with 2 or three controls and describe what you want/expect the controls to do?

Comment: The controls do not resize automatically. They keep the same position(x,y) after the form resets. So if the form starts at its base(800,800) for sizing and is resized to (500,500) a button that starts at(50,50) will stay there because it is not binded to the physical sides of the window but to the canvas that just grows rather than resized itself.

Comment: The "answer" is to place your controls into appropriate containers and then set their Anchor and/or Dock properties. The container you're probably looking for, though, is  a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)...

Comment: see details here on how to dock/anchor: [How to dock and anchor controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-dock-and-anchor?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: How does the columns and rows work on a TableLayoutPanel if they get resized so doesn't it get screwed up?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between docking and anchoring... don't they both place the controls on an object-oriented set of columns and rows?

Comment: You can setup column/rows to be either absolute in size, a percentage of the total size, or autosize (with combinations of all of these).  This way when the form is resized and your tablelayoutpanel is resized as well, all of the columns/rows resize within based on their sizing mode. Inside each cell of the tablelayoutpanel you can add controls that resize based on the size of the cell. The nested controls resize based on their Anchor/Dock properties, along with whether they "span" multiple rows/columns. You need to go searching for some tutorials on how all of these things go together...

Comment: You are going to want to read up on the various containers and experiment with them. There is no one-size-fits-all magic solution. None of them (as far as I know) can _resize_ the controls, they just re-arrange them. For what it's worth, this is _much_ easier to manage than native apps (well native apps back in the day)

Comment: Have you ever seen a programm that does that?

Comment: Mostly I just use anchor. When a control is anchored on a particular air it keeps the same distance between that side and the same side of the panel it's in. If the control is anchored on its right or bottom only it moves. If a control is anchored on left+right or top+bottom it stretches. Dock is just auto-anchor and a pain in the ass

Comment: Thank you guys so much will do!